# xlsxwriter bloomberg formula

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula, export-to-excel, bloomberg

I'm trying to get xlsxwriter to put a =BDP formula in a cell, but it results in an error when I try to open the excel output and the result is 0.0
Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!

```
sheet.write_formula('B3','=BDP("id","field")')
```

Comment: So you get 0 when you open the spreadsheet in Excel? What is the formula?

Comment: The formula is above, it's a BDP formula and I've tested that it works by itself. I feel like I'm missing something small like {} or something like that but I've tried different things and nothing fixed it

Comment: Do you get 0 when opening the spreadsheet in Excel or when reading the result from python?

Comment: I think the error is when python is writing the formula to excel, since there is nothing in the cell except 0.

Comment: Could you submit a bug report to the XlsxWriter GitHub with a small working program and a working file from Excel attached with a single formula and no other data (unless required for the example).

Comment: As a test, change the text "BDP" to "CONCAT" (which is a built-in Excel function), and leave everything else the same. This will tell you if there is something wrong in your Python code, something wrong with xlsxwriter, or something peculiar to the Bloomberg functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few changes required to get this working:

1. The formula needs to be prefixed with `_xll.` since it isn't a standard Excel formula and is only available via a plugin.
2. It should be an array formula.
3. The strings in the formula should be double quoted and not single quoted.

The following should work if you have the Bloomberg plugin installed:

```py
import xlsxwriter
    
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.write_array_formula('B4', '_xll.BDP(LEFT(C3,LEN(C3)-1)&" Corp", "Issuer")')

workbook.close()
```